# Why is PHPStorm throwing errors on twig access to app.request inside javascript?

Tags: symfony, twig, phpstorm

PHPStorm marks the following line as wrong:

```
if($("#heading{{ app.request.get('orderid')|number_format(0) }}")[0]) {
```

This is Twig inside Javascript (jQuery) accessing the symfony2 app. The errors in PHPStorm are:

```
Error:(334, 32) a term expected
Error:(334, 32) ':' expected
Error:(334, 40) a term expected
Error:(334, 41) Unknown function 'get'
Error:(334, 55) a term expected
Error:(334, 56) Unknown function 'number_format'
```

If I click on the light bulb to get some advice it's talking about "Invalid CSS function" for ".get".

[image]

I'm testing PHPStorm 9.0.2, switching from Netbeans. In Netbeans everything works fine.

Comment: Which errors are those? Screenshots with details please. Looks like some JSLint/JSHint or alike. I may also suggest to try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE (in case if there was an index/caches corruption).

Comment: OK. Thanks! I added a screenshot of the error when clicking on ".get". The editor thinks I'm using CSS ?! It is Twig. The file is also named .html.twig.
`File | Invalidate Caches...` didn't help.

Comment: Technically (considering the current limitations / how it all works) it is correct. The error location is inside `$("#heading...")` construct and CSS is forcibly injected there (as users want to see code completion for css symbols here) which overrides your lower level (in such case) Twig. Possible solution:  move `#heading` part inside the twig variable output -- something like `if($("{{ '#heading' ~ app.request.get('orderid')|number_format(0) }}")[0])`

Comment: But in any case -- file a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI -- I doubt anything can be done here without changing the code (unless you configure IDE to stop recognizing that code as JS so that CSS will not be injected in that place).